# Angular 2 multi select show only the static placeholder

Tags: css, angular, npm, responsive-design

I am new to angular 4 and I started working on angular multiselect and using the following npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

I could able to configure this properly and also getting the selected and deselected items/events.

Now my problem is to show only the placeholder text even though there are selected items or not. I want to ignore the selected items to be shown on the top.

If any item is selected from the item the multi select box is converted like the below

[image]

But I would like to keep the placeholder same like below if there are selected items or not.

[image]

I have been trying to get out it with responsive behavior. But not able to find the solution. Please help me.

Comment: Please share a minimal Stackblitz sample replicating this issue.

Comment: I don't have experience with this component, but it looks like you can customize the way a selected item is shown in the textbox:

`<angular2-multiselect ...>
  <c-badge>
           <ng-template let-item="item">
            <label style="margin: 0px;">{{item.itemName}}</label>
            ...
           </ng-template>
  </c-badge>  
</angular2-multiselect>
`
(cf. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown#template---for-custom-html-of-selected-item---badge)

Maybe you can try with an empty template?

Comment: Maybe you could try to ask your question on the developer's Github page. 
https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/issues

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like the feature is not there. However, there is a work around.

### Workaround

You could hide the list that is shown. In your CSS, you can add this:

```
.c-list{
   display: none;
}
```

This will not display back the 'Select Countries' placeholder, but it will partially achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Work Around**

Hide the list using CSS

```
angular2-multiselect /deep/ .c-list {
  display: none;
}
```

If you don't want the select items list growing, you can limit the number of badges shown by adding `badgeShowLimit` in the dropdown settings

[image]